# How to create a transaction input from tx id of UTXO?

Tags: transactions, utxo, createrawtransaction

I'm in the midst of working this github --> https://github.com/karask/python-bitcoin-utils/blob/master/examples/spend_p2sh_transaction.py

Sorry as I'm not that good in this. I would like to ask the following:

1. Where can I create this "transaction input from tx id of UTXO"?  This is for Bitcoin UTXO.

I mean is it using bitcoin node? vscode? python in Gitpods? I just want to know where I can run this and able to provide me the TXID along with the Transaction value in it. Like for example snapshot below:

[image]

Care to guide me? Please.. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't create it; you have it. It's the txid of the transaction that created the output you're trying to spend. Without it, you don't have any coins.

Answer (score 0):

[TxInput](https://github.com/karask/python-bitcoin-utils/blob/b31c82e7005e06db7f780688cfcd9332d479f39d/bitcoinutils/transactions.py#L27) is a class used in this example to define the input used for creating a transaction.

You can download and install [Atom Editor](https://atom.io/).
Install [script](https://atom.io/packages/script) package to run python code in atom.
Download and Install [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/).

Install bitcoin-utils library:

```
$ pip install bitcoin-utils
```

[image: Atom-Editor-Screenshot]

Comment: Hi @Prayank. Thanks for your reply. I did follow your instructions. However, in the Atom Editor, I'm unable to install bitcoin-utils library and unable to run the script like what you did in your snapshot. It stated here as                                                                          
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\GitPod\python-bitcoin-utils-master\bitcoinutils\utils.py", line 13, in <module>
  from bitcoinutils.constants import SATOSHIS_PER_BITCOIN
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bitcoinutils'
[Finished in 0.206s]

Comment: Open "command prompt" as an administrator and run the command "pip install bitcoin-utils" Relaunch Atom Editor and try to run the python code

Comment: Hi @Prayank. Thanks so much for your prompt reply and good guidance.                   
It really works except for the node_proxy.py  --> due to I think this is under "Testnet" and if I change to "Mainnet" do you think, it will automatically connect?             
Actually, I wanted to create a (new) UTXO with (new) Transaction in order to the TXID Input. do you think I can get it here in the bitcoin-utils library?   Or shall I make a new script for this? Please advise, thanks so much in advance.